# Как продолжить итерацию генератора python после остановки программы

Tags: python

Листая stackoverflow наткнулся на вопрос одного пользователя. И пока я писал ответ, он удалил вопрос, поэтому решил описать проблему и ее решение.

> Во время итерации, программа останавливается, сохраняя последнюю итерацию в файл. Нужно как-то восстановить выполнение программы с сохраненной итерации

```
def func(*args, repeat=1):
    pools = [tuple(pool) for pool in args] * repeat
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)

s = ['A', 'B', 'C']
f = func(s, repeat=3)

for index, step_func in enumerate(f):
    print(index, '\t', step_func)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Python нативна установлена библиотека itertools. В ней есть метод [islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)
Он позволяет начать итерацию с установленного шага.

Имея индекс последней итерации, можно запустить генератор с этой точки

```
step_iter = itertools.islice(func(s, repeat=3), l_index, None)
```

Полный код-пример

```
import itertools


def func(*args, repeat=1):
    pools = [tuple(pool) for pool in args] * repeat
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x + [y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)


s = ['A', 'B', 'C']
f = func(s, repeat=3)

last_index = 0
for index, step_func in enumerate(f):
    last_index = index
    print(index, '\t', step_func) # понятный вывод с индексами

    if index == 10:
        with open('last_index.temp', 'w') as file:
            file.write(str(last_index)) # сохраняем last_index в файл
        break  # моделируем вылет

print()  # для разделения

with open('last_index.temp', 'r') as file:
    l_index = int(file.readline()) + 1  # восстанавливаем из файла last_index
    step_iter = itertools.islice(func(s, repeat=3), l_index, None)  # запускаем генератор с сохраненного индекса
    for index, step_func in enumerate(step_iter):
        print(index + l_index, '\t', step_func) # понятный вывод с индексами
```

И получаем вот такой вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно, мы смоделировали вылет программы, потом прочитали последний индекс и запустили итерацию с него